# How do I use the value of a variable as a new variable without using a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code produces and appends a list with objects from a class in a for loop. I need to make several lists each with unique names. To achieve this I am trying to use variable values, without assigning the parent variable, while not creating a list.
EX.

```
x = list1                   
# (the value of X or list1)
(list1).append(value)
```

The goal is use the value of x to make a list, not

```
x.append(value)
```

but

```
list1.append(value)
```

I hope I've described my question well enough.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you looking for a copy?

Comment: if i understood you right, your code should be x=list1.copy(). That way modifying list1 won't affect x

Comment: You don't need lists with unique names; you need a dict that maps strings to lists.

Comment: It's unclear, but maybe you're looking for this? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341) BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and you'll probably want to read [ask] and [mre].